# How to send notification using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, notifications

What is the best way to send a notification to a friend of a facebook user that approved my app?

I know I can write on the friends' wall, but is there another way to leave **any kind** of notification?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of *notifications* and NOT *invitations*, no there are no more options. As you can see in the [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) documentation page, you can't access the friend's email.

Comment: thanks, so.. can a Facebook app send invitation without the multi selection dialog?

Comment: Not that I know (at least in the new Graph API), I don't know if capturing the submitting URL (using the multi selection) and trying to post to yourself server side works...but I doubt it

Answer (score 0):

```
$notificationdata = array(

    'href'=> 'https://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP/',

    'access_token'=> $app_token,

    'template'=> '180 char string as information'
);

$sendnotification = $facebook->api('/' . $user_id . '/notifications', 'post', 

$notificationdata);
```